# User input gets stuck in a loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I just started learning java today and decided to make a multiple choice quiz. The problem I've run into is that the user input gets stuck in a loop even if its one of the correct choices "a" or "b". This i my code:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String answer = input.nextLine();

    while(!answer.equals("a") || !answer.equals("b")) {
        System.out.println("Please enter one of the correct choices");
        answer = input.nextLine();
    }
```

Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Your `while` loop always evaluates to true so it will loop forever. Right now the the expression of the `while` loop will evaluate to `true` if the input is not "a" or not "b". I think you want not ("a" or "b"). I put parenthesis there as a hint.

Comment: is this what you mean: answer != (a || b)

Comment: Sort of, but the exact syntax would be `!(answer.equals("a") || answer.equals("b"))`, which, by DeMorgan's Laws, is equivalent to what Talendar's answer is. So, you were on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the usage of the `OR operator ("||")` in your while loop conditions. While these conditions are true, your loop will keep executing. Since you are checking if the user input is different than "a" **or** different than "b", the condition will always be true, because the input can't be "a" and "b" at the same time.

You should use the `AND operator ("&&")` in this case. See below:

```
while(!answer.equals("a") && !answer.equals("b")) {
```

This will return true (and thus keep executing the loop) if the input is, at the same time, different than "a" and different than "b".

**Edit:**

[Alerra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7151380/alerra) also proposed a very interesting way to achieve the same as shown above. See below:

```
while(!(answer.equals("a") || !answer.equals("b"))) {
```

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks so much for your help

Comment: You are welcome! If this answered your question, please, select this as the answer so it can help others in the future.

Comment: How do I do so? Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: There is a grayed out "tick" icon on the left side of my answer (close to the "up" and "down" arrows). Just click it and this answer will be accepted by you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the || operator, if answer is A than it is not B inversely if it is B than it is not A

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!(answer.equals("a") || !answer.equals("b")))
```

You can use truth table of `OR` to think of this question:

```
True True = True
True False = True
False True = True
False False = False
```

So if the user are not answering `A` and `B`, you want to keep the while loop running, inverse the `False`, so that the loop continue.  If user answer any of `A` and `B`, it will break the loop!

Inverse OR truth table:

```
True True = False
True False = False
False True = False
False False = True
```